# InaSAFE plugin OSM download get error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

[image]

I am gettting the following error and not able to use this plugin.

```
Error transferring http://osm.inasafe.org/roads-shp?bbox=31.19946,30.17477,31.20529,30.178498qgis_version=310028&lang=en&inasafe_version=5.0.0
- server replied: Origin Error
```

Answer (score 3):

because the server is down

> http://osm.inasafe.org/
>
> Error 520 Ray ID: 560fb1f7a99df981 • 2020-02-06 19:57:59 UTC Web
>   server is returning an unknown error